# simultaneously access a method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, concurrency, asp.net-mvc-5

I'll tell my question in simple way.
There is a receipt object which pass from the UI. But the object doesn't have receipt number. It is generated next receipt number in the code. Below is the sequence. Imagine that, this workflow is needed only 2 db tables and there is no link between these two. one is for save data to "Receipt" (used to save receipt data) table and the other is "GenerateNumber" (used to keep number sequence) table.

1. Generate next receipt number.
2. Generated receipt number assign to object property.
3. Create the receipt.
4. Commit changes.

> Code

```
//customerReceipt obejct has all data except receipt number.

  AutoGenerateDocumentNo autoGen = new AutoGenerateDocumentNo();
  autoGen =_autoGenDocService.GenerateNextNumberSequence();//This method use to get next number
  customerReceipt.ReceiptNo = autoGen.GeneratedNumber;    
  CreateCustomerReceiptHeader(customerReceipt); //Save function
  Save(); // commite changes (this commit will efeect to both receipt and generate next number table)
```

In above code has only one commit. but when access this method simultaneously it is generated few receipts from one receipt number. But I don't know how to avoid this. i just used "Lock" key word for avoiding this. But it won't work. then I try, commit save inside **GenerateNextNumberSequence** method. It also doesn't work.

Please give me a direction to do above task.

> Update 1

This project is used Entity-framework for data manipulation. In here, it is not going to use any stored procedures.

Comment: For starters, why don't you let your _database_ generate your number? They are _very good_ at it. Secondly, I guess we need to see what your _autogenDocService does, because I have the feeling it might very well be giving you the same number until that number is committed to the database.

Comment: I agree with oerkelens: If you have SQL have a look at SCOPE_IDENTITY

Comment: Thanks for reply. But the my clients need to replace their existing system. hence they need to start receipt number from any number. (Eg: if starting from 5000, then my system receipt number is "REC0005001") In that case I cannot use db auto generate number.

Comment: If they only need to replace their system once, you only need to set a starting number once, which can generally be done, e.g. `IDENTITY(5000,1)` if it's SQL Server, `ALTER SEQUENCE` if it's PostgreSQL, and so on.

Comment: Cant we do this with entity framework...?